# What does it mean for a function to be oddly and evenly symmetric?

Tags: notation, even-and-odd-functions

From understanding, a function describes a relationship between multiple variables, and has unique values across all possible values on one axis while not duplicating violating a vertical line test to determine if values get repeated, and can also potentially be symmetric.

Symmetry, from what I understand, is a property of a function that exists in two types, either even or odd.   Both seem clear in my mind to indicate information preservation of that function after that function is transformed from that Quadrant alone into the possible quadrants that do not cross into a quadrant where the remainder of the function exists.

If a function has symmetry about the x axis we reflect off the y axis check if there is a match in corresponding values then we get an even match on both sides then the function seems clear in my mind to be symmetric.

For odd, my reasoning, without looking for the formulaic definition is to construct a orthogonal line, which I am assuming as at a 45 degree from the x, y axis.   If this function is rotated from Quadrant 1 to the Quadrant 3 (180 degrees), as an example using the newly constructed orthogonal axis, then it becomes clear to me that the function is becomes symmetric after that rotation but across the orthogonal diagonal.

What characteristic other than observation of sign flip across the x, y, values, makes it so that a name such as odd is designated to describe this type of symmetry, and also does that characteristic apply to even functions too?    Is there a numeric, or graphical reason which I am not seeing directly that can simply explain the reasoning being the two names, even ( number divisible by 2 ) and another odd ( not divisible into an whole number by another even number )?

Comment: I see the fact that a plane or line of reflection is present in both cases,  how they relate to odd and even numbers, I have not yet cleared up

Comment: From word understanding, they can be subdivided into two equal components that are whole numbers if even as mentioned in the question, but not so when they are odd, the only analogy I can think of this case is if I cant have a mirror copy of the number divided then the number is odd, then one of the parts will be a factional number.  Not of course the case in even numbers, which can divide the two portions into two separate but equal number of components.  Something that comes to mind is that a number is even if I can produce duplicate instances of its additive constituent components.

Comment: If x raised to the third power is as defined as oddly symmetric, is rotated from Quadrant1 to Quadrant 3, I see how somewhat the function becomes drastically different, how I still cant connect the dots

Comment: Looks like I have connected it in my mind, a function with a sign component on flip that has a odd power of -1 is an odd function by means of calculating the sign

Comment: I also just re-discovered that f(x) = 0 is both even and odd

Answer (score 2):

The most basic examples of even functions are $f(x)=x^n$ with even $n$, the most basic examples of even functions are $f(x)=x^n$ with odd $n$.
Note that for even $n$, we have $(-x)^n=x^n$, so the graph is symmetric under reflection at the $y$-axis, and for odd $n$, we have $(-x)^n=-x^n$, so we have to reflect both at the $y$ and the $x$ axis (or equivalently: rotate by $180^\circ$ around the origin, aka. a point reflection at the origin).

A general function is called even/odd if it has one of these symmetries just like the even/odd powers.

Comment: So it seems that odd/even is definitely linked to the odd even powers of the quadradic, cubic, or even the periodic functions, defined by a series using odd/even powers of functions

Answer (score 0):

Even symmetry: $f(-x)=f(x)$, e.g. $f(x)=\cos x$ or $f(x)=x^2$.

The graph is symmetric about the $y$-axis.

Odd symmetry: $f(-x)=-f(x)$, e.g. $f(x)=\sin x$ or $f(x)=x^3$

The graph is symmetric with the reflection in first the $y$- then the $x$-axis.

Comment: Actually I am comfortable with the definition of the sign flip across x, y, for two types of symmetry, but unclear on why the sign flip relates to if at all to the symmetry with reflection description provided in the question.

Comment: That's just nomenclature.

Comment: According to wiki: "They are named for the parity of the powers of the power functions which satisfy each condition: the function $f(x)=x^n$ is an even function if $n$ is an even integer, and it is an odd function if $n$ is an odd integer."

Comment: I'm trying to get this connected with its average value which seems to resonate in my mind with being with the type of function,  which can evaluate to exactly 0 when calculating the indefinite integral, but positive for sure for an even function, hopefully even a periodic that integrates indefinitely a region and shape value that can be divided into 2, hopefully more regions of equal number, like an even wave function